# c# system.IO.Directory.GetDirectories нужен метод для сортировке по Дате

Tags: c#, массивы, сортировка, дата

я начинающий в c#. 
Написана довольно большая консольная программа в ней множество раз получается массив методом system.IO.Directory.GetDirectories() и методов которые принимают этот массив, и используют из него пути файлов

Всё работает, но требуется пост сортировка по дате.Которая бы оставила массив путей

Не могли бы вы помочь с этим. Подсказать метод принимающей готовый массив и выдающий отсортированный

Comment: `.OrderBy()` linq....

Comment: Статический `Array.Sort`, экземплярный `List.Sort`.

Comment: Чтобы узнать дату создания папки используйте класс `DirectoryInfo`